# Text gone when I set background for button

Tags: android, layout

```
<Button
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@drawable/banner_btn_bg"
                        android:text="ABCXYZDEF"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

I want to set background for my button, but the text will be gone when I set it. I wonder why my text will appear when I set background to any color but it will be gone when I set image? Btw, the image is a grey one not white as text.How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Text is drawn on the image, you just can not see it..

Try changing the text color to `RED` or `BLUE` or a **primary color**, since your backgroud is grey